# how large size support `crontab.txt` on linux serve?

Tags: cron

I have a long long list of task list in `crontab.txt`, my `crontab.txt` over 5MB, will it cause fault in linux serve? (has lunux dad a limit size requiry?)
And is it good to write a task list like this?(mixed order time table) Thanks.

```
1 * * * * commond(a group of task run every minute)
...
10 10 * * * commond(a group of task run every 10 minute per hour)
...
1 2,4,6,8 * * * commond(a group of task run every 2,4,6,8 hour)
...
```

Comment: FYI: `1 * * * * commond(a group of task run every minute)` won't run a task every minute - it'll run the task one minute after each hour.

Answer (score -1):

You can schedule tasks via cron. And normally the size of the file will not affect the server.

Regards,
Ajo

Comment: -1; the OP clearly knows what `cron` does, and I don't really think that this answers the question.

Comment: @nickgrim,  because I have not yet used cron on a linux service. So I want to ask if there has a limit in  `crontab.txt` size. and the correctly write standard. (if the list order a mixed date will cause fault...)  Thanks.